# Reading txt file, then re organizing it to an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, printf

So basically what I need to do is:

Read a text file like this:

```
[Student ID], [Student Name], Asg 1, 10, Asg 2, 10, Midterm, 40, Final, 40
01234567, Timture Choi, 99.5, 97, 100.0, 99.0
02345678, Elaine Tam, 89.5, 88.5, 99.0, 100
```

and present it like this (with calculations of rank and average):

```
ID Name Asg 1 Asg 2 Midterm Final Overall Rank

01234567 Timture Choi 99.5 97.0 100.0 99.0 99.3 1

02345678 
Elaine Tam 89.5 88.5 99.0 100.0 97.4 2

 Average: 94.5 92.75 99.5 99.5 98.3
```

Using `printf()` function

now this is what I have done so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class AssignmentGrades {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner filename = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fn = filename.nextLine(); //scannig the file name
        System.out.println("Enter your name of file : ");

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fn+".txt");

        BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader (fr);
        String list;

        while((list = br.readLine()) !=null) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

So I can ask the user for the name of the file, then read it and print.

Now.. I'm stuck. I think I need to probably put it in to array and split?

```
String firstrow = br.readLine();
String[] firstrow = firstrow.split(", ");
```

something like that?.. ugh ive been stuck here for more than an hour

I really need help!! I appreciate your attention!! ( I started to learn java this week)

Comment: `Scanner` can be used to read integers etc based on some separator (here `, `). see [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for splitting the input line just read from the file

1. Using String object's **split()** method which would return an array. Read more about the split [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm).
2. **StringTokenizer Class** - This class can be used to divide the input string into separate tokens based on a set of delimeter. [Here](http://crunchify.com/java-stringtokenizer-and-string-split-example/) is a good tutorial to get started.

You should be able to get more examples using google :)

In case you want to parse integers from String. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Here I store the columns as an array of `String`s and I store the record set as an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of `String` arrays. In the `while` loop if the column set is not initialized yet (first iteration) I initialize it with the `split`. Otherwise I add the `split` to the `ArrayList`. Import `java.util.ArrayList`.

```
    String[] columns = null;
    ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String list;

    while((list = br.readLine()) !=null) {
        if (columns != null) {
            columns = list.split(", ");
        } else {
            values.add(list.split(", "));
        }
    }
    fr.close();
```